# Why handleResponse(URI url, HttpMethod method, ClientHttpResponse response) method of RestTemplate.class is getting called for a 200 Succeess response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, resttemplate

I am calling an external API from my code using **RestTemplate** like below:

```
       try {

            responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
                    UploadResonse.class);
        } catch (BusinessException ex) {
            fetchErrorResponseEntity = ex.getResponseEntity();
            if (fetchErrorResponseEntity.getStatusCodeValue() == 404) {
                throw new BusinessException(ex.getMessage(), ErrorResponse.NOT_FOUND);
            } else if (fetchErrorResponseEntity.getStatusCodeValue() == 500) {
                throw new BusinessException(ex.getMessage(),
                                          ErrorResponse.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            } else if (fetchErrorResponseEntity.getStatusCodeValue() == 400) {
                throw new BusinessException(ex.getMessage(), ErrorResponse.INVALID_REQUEST);
            }

        }
```

This API call is returning **200 Success** but when I debug it, it still goes to **handleResponse(URI url, HttpMethod method, ClientHttpResponse response)** method of **RestTemplate.class**

And then it's coming to my RestTemplateErrorHandler.java file

```
    @Override
public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse)
        throws IOException {
    return clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK;
}

@Override
public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse)
        throws IOException {
    String errMessage = getErrMessage(clientHttpResponse);
    HttpStatus status = clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode();
    switch (status) {
    case BAD_REQUEST: // 400
        throw new BusinessException(errMessage,
                ErrorResponse.INVALID_REQUEST);
    case NOT_FOUND:
      throw new BusinessException(errMessage, ErrorResponse.NOT_FOUND);
    case SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE: // 503
        throw new BusinessException(errMessage, ErrorResponse.TIME_OUT);
    case METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED: // 405
    case INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: // 500
    default:
        throw new BusinessException(errMessage,
                ErrorResponse.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Can someone lease help me to understand if it's the correct behaviour.
I suspect that if the response is **200 Success** it should not go to the **RestTemlate.class** and **RestTemplateErrorHandler.class**
This behaviour is creating problem when API return **201 Created** status, that time it goes to **handleError()** method and return the default case **INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR**
Can someone please help me here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will call the error handler every time the response is not **200 OK**, event if it is successful like **201 Created**.

```
@Override
public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse)
        throws IOException {
    return clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK;
}
```

Try changing the implementation to the following:

```
@Override
public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse)
        throws IOException {
    return !clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful();
}
```

This is better suited for your needs as it will consider all **2xx** status as successful requests instead of only **200 OK**.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#handleResponse-java.net.URI-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse-) method `handleResponse()` as it name suggests will handle the given response, perform appropriate logging and invoke the `ResponseErrorHandler` (if needed) which is interface used by the RestTemplate to determine whether a particular response has an error or not.
`RestTemplateErrorHandler` class implements implements `ResponseErrorHandler`.

If the `hasError()` method returns `true` then Spring will automatically call the `handleError()` method. This is the flow.

If you check implementation for `handleResponse` method, given below, you will see that there is a call to `hasError` method to check if the response has any errors. Default implementation of `hasError` method will return true is response code is `4XX` or `5XX`. If there is no errors, method will proceed execution and handleError method won't be invoked, as I explained above.

```
protected void handleResponse(URI url, HttpMethod method, ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler = this.getErrorHandler();
        boolean hasError = errorHandler.hasError(response);
        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            try {
                this.logger.debug(method.name() + " request for \"" + url + "\" resulted in " + response.getRawStatusCode() + " (" + response.getStatusText() + ")" + (hasError ? "; invoking error handler" : ""));
            } catch (IOException var7) {
                ;
            }
        }
        if (hasError) {
            errorHandler.handleError(url, method, response);
        }

    }
```

In code you posted `hasError` will return **true** for all response codes that are **different** from `200`. That's why `handleError` is invoked.

Comment: yup RestTemplateErrorHandler.class implements ResponseErrorHandler.class and I overridden the hasError() method. What I understood from your details is that handleResponse() method will get called everytime whther the reponse is success or filed and based on the logic in overridden hasError() method thingswill get executed....right?

Comment: @Tech_sharma Yes, that's correct.